# How to make flow separation effect?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, effects

I'm making a spaceship scene, like there is an ship cutting through the sky and I want to make this effect: (look at wing tips)
[image]

I'm using old Blender v2.66 and Blender Render.

I think it's maybe possible with particles, but I don't know how.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that it will be pretty hard to make an answer for 2.66. I personally don't even remember what changed since then.

Comment: You can maybe write how you do it in your version, and I'll try to do it. It will be useful for people on new versions anyways.

Comment: try a moving smoke emitter with temp at 1.0 so it does not rise and domain with no turbulence and no dissipation

Comment: okay wait, i'll give it a try

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny  Tell me how to do that, I'm slightly dumb. Or just noob. Actually both, but anyways.